# Time machine is not including new directories in its backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

My Time Machine is going for a year quite strong, but I recently noticed it is not including new directories in its backup. Basically new directories are being excluded by rule or error and I'd like some help figuring out which.

1. It still *does* its normal backup. The system log files says:

   ```
   Dec 21 19:35:59 leosbook com.apple.backupd[2218]: Starting standard backup
   Dec 21 19:35:59 leosbook com.apple.backupd[2218]: Backing up to: /Volumes/Wisdom/Backups.backupdb
   Dec 21 19:36:02 leosbook com.apple.backupd[2218]: 2.28 GB required (including padding), 319.50 GB available
   Dec 21 19:36:04 leosbook com.apple.backupd[2218]: [...]
   Dec 21 19:36:07 leosbook com.apple.backupd[2218]: Backup completed successfully.
   ```
2. The newly created directory is *not* excluded. Checking via `tmutil` reveals in Terminal:

   ```
   > tmutil isexcluded "/Users/bongu/Pictures/Import/Eye-Fi/NewDir"
   +    /Users/bongu/Pictures/Import/Eye-Fi/NewDir
   ```
3. However the new directory `NewDir` never gets backed up. The directory is not part of the latest backup:

   ```
   > ls /Volumes/Wisdom/Backups.backupdb/leosbook/latest/book/Users/bongu/Pictures/Import/Eye-Fi/NewDir
   ls: /Volumes/[...]: no such file or directory
   ```

How does this possibly happen? And any idea how can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you sure the path in step 3 is correct? Does `ls /Volumes/Wisdom/Backups.backupdb/leosbook/latest/book/Users/bongu/Pictures/Import/Eye-Fi` produce a valid result?

Comment: Yes, ls /Volumes/Wisdom/Backups.backupdb/leosbook/latest/book/Users/bongu/Pictures/Impor‌t/Eye-Fi exists and ists all thensub folders until the 13 Dec 2011 - new directories don't get backed up. The same is true for new folders under `~/Desktop`.

Comment: what is the output of _tmutil isexcluded *_

Comment: @geoO Cannot check anymore. I have recreated the machine later for other reasons.

Comment: I think this question is now too specific to be still on any real use. Is there any way to "close" it?

Comment: If someone has a new instance of this, you can flag this for reopening or ask a new question. Since the OP no longer can reproduce the issue and hasn't accepted an answer, this will attract more guesses and no resolution so a closed state can preserve the information, but not attract more guesses.

Answer (score 0):

In your *System Preferences << Time Machine* you can tell Time Machine which files to skip. Maybe you listed the directory in this list?

Comment: I Chcked: No, it is not listed there. (`tmutil isexcluded` should tell me that as well.)